# How to create image and/or graph in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am porting an app over from Delphi (Pascal form with an Access database) to operate strictly in Access. I have already done all the SQL and data handling successfully; now I need to present it graphically. The form features a full-version graph, and then a zoomed-in subset of that graph:

[image: ORIGINAL]

I attempted to reproduce the graph as a CHART, and as an Excel object. (Although I did not succeed with either of these approaches, I acknowledge that the solution may be in there somewhere.)

Ultimately, I did reproduce the full graph (at center right) - but to do so, I had to create hundreds of individual picture elements, and I ran up against the "number of objects limit" before I could complete the "ZOOMBOX"... Clearly the wrong approach.

I have plotted the elements of the graph (a subset of which would, of course, be the zoombox) into a table, which *could* be used as a sort of "paint-by-numbers" guide.

[image: GRAPHTABLE]

Comment: I don't see how chart object could accomplish anything like this. Perhaps a subform bound to that table and using textbox Conditional Formatting could emulate the 'banding'.

Comment: Is your graph just text in boxes like in the images? If yes, your best bet is to create a table with the columns as fields and the records as lines, use VBA to empty and fill the table with values and then just open it in read-only mode. The table will maintain the formatting, you will just have to adjust the width of each columns once.

Comment: @SunKnight0 The desired graph/images would resemble those on the right side of the top image as closely as possible. The data is plotted out in GRAPHTABLE (bottom image) with each "cell" representing a square, and the values in them representing the vb color code (1 being black, 15 being light gray, 16 being dark gray, etc.). The values on the left side of the GRAPHTABLE are static (the structure of the graph) while the values on the right (15s and 16s) are dynamic (the data of the graph).

When I attempted embedding Excel, I did not know what formulae to use to extract the data.

Comment: @SunKnight0 Wait - I guess I don't need to have formulae in the cells, do I? Just utilize my GRAPHTABLE as a guide to sending InteriorColor data to the cells, right?

Comment: You don't even need that. Use same foreground and background color `conditional formatting` and just dump your GRAPHRABLE values into the Excel sheet.

Comment: I tried it and realized that, with the Excel spreadsheet embedded into the database, I do not know how to address it! The embedded spreadsheet apparently does not have a name per se. So how does one address it from without once it is embedded?

I need to either a) SEND the "condition" data to each individual cell so that the CF might do its thing, or b) DRAW data into the cells with formulae that would address the Access table. I am experienced with VBA but haven't a clue what that would look like...

Comment: Thank you for the input on this, but I believe that I have reached a dead end on this approach. The (over-)extended number of objects it required made it too kludgy.